Changing decimal places in Tibble with both numeric and character values in a single column
I need to make the decimal places rounded to 3 in the following tibble, but some rows have numeric numbers and some have character "-"...
I would normally use
Example Tibble
Tibble = structure(list(Variable = c("Temperature", "Mercury", "Molybdenum"
), Test = c("ANOVA", "-", "ANOVA"), Transformation = c("None", 
"-", "None"), `OT(P)` = c("2.30066508038429e-08", 
"-", "1.073364034195e-05"), `RvOSP-v` = c("0.00278524117210566", 
"-", "1.88882927695255e-05"), `RvOSdiff` = c("0.333333333333332", 
"-", "3.66666666666667"), `RvESP-v` = c("4.98892422928776e-08", 
"-", "0.417855021742739"), `RvESdiff` = c("-2.23333333333333", 
"-", "-0.333333333333333")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

I would normally use
Tibble %>%  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 3))

Perhaps Tibble %>% mutate(across(4:8, ~as.numeric(.x) %>% round(digits = 3)))?

Everything is character!!! see str(Tibble).

Check how you read the data into R. For example, read.table has na.string argument, read_csv has na argument. You can use them to specify string(s) to be treated as NAs. You can also specify a column class as numeric in the reading function.

You can use parse_number from readr package and get no warnings:
library(readr)
Tibble %>% 
   mutate(across(4:8, ~parse_number(.x, na = "-")) %>% round(3))

     Variable  Test Transformation OT(P) RvOSP-v RvOSdiff RvESP-v RvESdiff
1 Temperature ANOVA           None     0   0.003    0.333   0.000   -2.233
2     Mercury     -              -    NA      NA       NA      NA       NA
3  Molybdenum ANOVA           None     0   0.000    3.667   0.418   -0.333


First of all, you cannot have both numeric and character values in a single column;
> str(Tibble)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Variable        : chr  "Temperature" "Mercury" "Molybdenum"
 $ Test            : chr  "ANOVA" "-" "ANOVA"
 $ Transformation  : chr  "None" "-" "None"
 $ Overall Test (P): chr  "2.30066508038429e-08" "-" "1.073364034195e-05"
 $ RvOSP-v         : chr  "0.00278524117210566" "-" "1.88882927695255e-05"
 $ RvOSdiff        : chr  "0.333333333333332" "-" "3.66666666666667"
 $ RvESP-v         : chr  "4.98892422928776e-08" "-" "0.417855021742739"
 $ RvESdiff        : chr  "-2.23333333333333" "-" "-0.333333333333333"

It looks like you have converted these columns to character to replace NAs or zeros with dashes, and now you want to get your desired precision. I would suggest rounding prior to changing the class of columns.
But if you must do the rounding for this specific dataset (with character columns), the you can achieve that with a couple of ifelse blocks, checking whether as.numeric() returns a number or not, do the rounding (I also did signif for to preserve numbers with scientific notation), and then finally save/write/mutate the result as a character back to the column.
library(dplyr)

Tibble %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(.x)),
                          ifelse(abs(as.numeric(.x)) < 0.001, 
                                  as.character(signif(as.numeric(.x), 
                                                      digits=2)),
                                  as.character(round(as.numeric(.x), 3))),
                          .x))) ## This will return some warnings

#>      Variable  Test Transformation   OT(P) RvOSP-v RvOSdiff RvESP-v RvESdiff
#> 1 Temperature ANOVA           None 2.3e-08   0.003    0.333   5e-08   -2.233
#> 2     Mercury     -              -       -       -        -       -        -
#> 3  Molybdenum ANOVA           None 1.1e-05 1.9e-05    3.667   0.418   -0.333

Created on 2024-11-07 with reprex v2.0.2
